# Using Collect to group derivatives together

Tags: simplifying-expressions, products

Is there a way to combine derivatives that are a result from the product rule back together using Collect.

For example, I'd like to collect

```
x Dt[y,b] + y Dt[x,b]
```

back to

```
Dt[x y,b]
```

I can do this with a rule:

```
Rule = {x Dt[y,b] + y Dt[x,b] -> Dt[xy,b]};
x Dt[y,b] + y Dt[x,b]/.Rule
```

But this forces me to use a new variable: xy instead of the actual product of x and y. Moreover, I have many different rules to follow so typing all those out would be taxing. Has anyone else tried doing this and succeeded?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Note that `Rule` is a built-in `Protected` symbol.  You shouldn't/can't use it as a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't actually call it "Rule" in my code but I know that Mathematica warns about protected names.

Answer (score 3):

`Dt`, by its nature, will apply the derivative rules until it can't.  You could make it [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html).

```
rule = {x Dt[y, b] + y Dt[x, b] -> Inactive[Dt][x y, b]};
x Dt[y, b] + y Dt[x, b] /. rule
(*  Inactive[Dt][x y, b]  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Some generic transformations:

```
With[{dt = Inactive[Dt]},
 byparts = # /. Plus[f_ dt[g_, v_], rest___] :> Simplify[dt[f g, v] + rest - g dt[f, v]] &;
 sum = # /. Plus[dt[f_, v_], dt[g_, v_], rest___] :> dt[f + g, v] + rest &;
 ];
pauseDt = Inactivate[#, Dt] &;
```

Example

```
Simplify[
 Dt[x, b] + y Dt[x, b] + x Dt[y, b] // pauseDt,
 TransformationFunctions -> {byparts, sum, Automatic}]
(*  Inactive[Dt][x (1 + y), b]  *)
```

Check:

```
Expand@Activate[%]
(*  Dt[x, b] + y Dt[x, b] + x Dt[y, b]  *)
```

Comment: This is really useful. Do you know if there is a way to also combine Dt[x,a] and Dt[y,a] into Dt[x+y,a] so  that I might do x+y->z, for example.

Comment: @LuisNegrete Can you not do it in the same way?  You may find `Inactivate[expr, Dt]` and `Activate[]` helpful if you're dealing with complicated expressions.